# Is there a way to index only a section of an item in a string in Python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm making an infinite text-based survival game for my computer science/cyber security class in school. I'm working in Python and have an inventory[] list, which I use .append(item) to add items and materials to the inventory list. Then I also use seperate variables to actually give the strings meaning, but that is unrelated. Each item is written in the format "item, (item amount)" in the inventory list. I need to know if I can use .index() to search for only the "item, " section of the element in the list, so that I can edit only the (item amount) section of the element, and if there isn't I need to know if there is an alternative. Preferably without undoing the method I'm using with the inventory being a list, since much of the game is built around that method.

```
materials = ["log", "stone", "sticks", "string", "junk", "rocks", "cloth", "herbs"]
inventory = []
def material_gathering():
    global health, hunger, log_amount, stone_amount, stick_amount, string_amount, junk_amount, rock_amount, cloth_amount, herb_amount
    material_type = random.choice(materials)
    material_amount = random.randint(2, 10)
    health = health - material_amount
    hunger = hunger + material_amount
    if material_type == "log":
        log_amount = log_amount + material_amount
        print("You gathered " + str(material_amount) + " logs.")
        if "log, " in inventory:
            log_position = inventory.index("log, ")
            inventory[log_position] = ("log, " + str(log_amount))
        else:
            inventory.append("log, " + str(log_amount))
```

Comment: A `dict` would work much better for this than a `list`. The key would be the item name, and the value would be the amount. That way you no longer have to convert to and from string.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking us "can I use it?"  You have the ultimate authority in front of you -- we expect you to *try* it before posting.

Comment: How does one make an infinite game in a finite computer?

Comment: Green Cloak Guy, thank you for your suggestion, Prune, I did try it I just worded my question incorrectly, the code above does not work I was asking for a solution

Comment: Strings do not have "sections". If you want to search a *substring*, then the first thing you should do is *check the documentation* for the `.index` method and see how it works. The second thing is to come up with the *rule that tells you* where the substring is that you want to search. Or, as the others suggested, you can use data with a more sensible structure in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Green Cloak Guy for your comment, using a dictionary worked really well, I converted the list inventory to a dictionary, then replaced all of the inventory.append with inventory["item"] = item_amount, that way it removes the need for all of the item searching and indexing, ETC.